# Change Branch Cut for DifferentialRoot

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

The differential equation

```
eqn = (16 + q) g[q] + 4 q (-3 + q^2) g'[q] - 4 q^2 (-1 + q^2) g''[q] == 0
```

is singular at `{-1,0,1}`.  Nonetheless

```
g /. Flatten@DSolve[{eqn, g[2] == 0, g'[2] == 1}, g, q]
```

gives a well-behaved numerical function

```
(* DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalX]}, 
   {(-16 - \[FormalX])*\[FormalY][\[FormalX]] - 4*\[FormalX]*(-3 + \[FormalX]^2)*
   \[FormalY]'[\[FormalX]] + (-4*\[FormalX]^2 + 4*\[FormalX]^4)*
   \[FormalY]''[\[FormalX]] == 0, \[FormalY][2] == 0, \[FormalY]'[2] == 1}], 
    Function[\[FormalX], {{Re[\[FormalX]] <= 1, Im[\[FormalX]] == 0}}]] *)
```

It has a branch cut on the real axis for `q <= 1`, as indicated by the last line.  Elsewhere, it can be evaluated numerically, e.g.,

```
%[3.]
(* 1.15068 *)
```

However, I would like a solution valid in the region `0 < q < 1` as well and have tried,

```
g /. Flatten@DSolve[{eqn, g[1/2] == 0, g'[1/2] == 1}, g, q]
(* DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalX]}, 
   {(-16 - \[FormalX])*\[FormalY][\[FormalX]] - 4*\[FormalX]*(-3 + \[FormalX]^2)*
   \[FormalY]'[\[FormalX]] + (-4*\[FormalX]^2 + 4*\[FormalX]^4)*
   \[FormalY]''[\[FormalX]] == 0, \[FormalY][1/2] == 0, \[FormalY]'[1/2] == 1}], 
    Function[\[FormalX], {{Re[\[FormalX]] <= 1, Im[\[FormalX]] == 0}}]] *)
```

The branch cut has not moved.  Consequently, this expression evaluates numerically nowhere.  My questions are:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there a work-around?

Comment: What about doing transforming q -> 1/z and solving the ODE for z?

Comment: @CarlWoll  Great idea, which puts the branch cut where desired and evaluates correctly.  Perhaps, you would care to post it as an answer.  I remain inclined to describe the behavior in the question as a bug, not because the branch cut is in the wrong place but because the solution produced evaluates no where to a numerical result.  What are your thoughts?